# How should I implement IDownloadProgressChangedCallback using WIN32OLE?

Tags: ruby, windows, com, win32ole, wuapi

I'd like to download Windows updates by use of [WIN32OLE](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html) in Ruby. I'm running into issues knowing which COM object to use in order to get the arguments needed by [IUpdateDownloader::BeginDownload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386132(v=vs.85).aspx) . For the time being, I can execute the synchronous version of downloading updates, but I would really like to know how I can go about using the asynchronous method.

Something such as the following works now:

```
require 'win32ole'

muSession = WIN32OLE.new('Microsoft.Update.Session')
availableUpdates = muSession.CreateUpdateSearcher().Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'").Updates

muUpdateColl = WIN32OLE.new('Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl')
availableUpdates.each do |update|
    update.AcceptEula()
    muUpdateColl.Add(update)
end

updateDownloader = WIN32OLE.new('Microsoft.Update.Session').CreateUpdateDownloader()
updateDownloader.Updates = muUpdateColl

downloadResult = updateDownloader.Download()
```

However, instead of invoking "Download()", I would like to use "BeginDownload()". How can I instantiate [IDownloadProgressChangedCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385872(v=vs.85).aspx) (for example). I think doing so may be obvious in C#, but using WIN32OLE, I am not sure how to create the object.